# diagrama de clases y sus metodos

Tags: uml

Estoy construyendo el diagrama de clases para la **sistematización de un consultorio odontológico**; donde
en este diagrama tengo definido por ejemplo mis clases `administrador`, `inventarios`,`agendaOdontologica` entre otros.

La clase `administrador` tiene métodos como:

```
. crearAgendaOdontologica()
. eliminarAgenda()
. crearInventarios()
.
.
.
entre otros...
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Estos métodos que acabo de mencionar pertenecen a la clase `agendaOdontologica` e `inventarios` respectivamente o pertenecen a la clase `administrador`> ya que estas son acciones que el puede hacer. Pero entonces me genera la duda si esto es asi, entonces qué métodos tendría la clase `agendaOdontológica`, y para hacerlo mas general que criterios debo tener en cuenta para asignar correctamente un método a una clase?

Pdta: he mirado videos y documentación pero siempre encuentro lo mismo y no he podido resolver mi inquietud, agradezco link donde aparezca la info ademas de sus comentarios, gracias y feliz noche.

Comment: Si el `administrador` tendrá una sola agenda, no necesita un método `crearAgenda()`, si habrá más de una lo ideal sería delegar eso a un `GestorDeAgendas` cuya función es la administración de las agendas. De igual forma con los `inventarios` su gestión debe ser responsabilidad de otra clase. Qué métodos pueden pertenecer a la clase `Agenda`? los métodos que tienen que ver con la razón de ser de una agenda como: agregarNota, borrarNota, buscarNota, etc.

Comment: gracias, pero quizás no me hice entender, mi confusión radica en el caso particular de la clase administrador y la clase agendaOdontologica donde en la agenda se crearan varias agendas de diferentes odontologos donde tendra dias disponibles, horas disponibles y el nombre del especialista y la especilidad, entonces mi duda consiste basicamente que no se donde poner por ejemplo el metodo crearAgenda o eliminarAgenda, ya que como he leido, creo que en teoria, iria en la clase agenda pero tmbn se que esa es una accion del administrador, no? entonces nose donde poner ese tio de metodos, me explico?

Comment: Entonces me parece que se aplica el segundo caso, un `GestorDeAgendas`, tal vez el nombre no sea el adecuado pero la idea es esa, que cada agenda independiente sea administrada por algo. Y el administrador le dirá al gestor: gestor creáme una nueva agenda. gestor en la agenda x programa un nuevo turno , etc

Comment: lo que te entendi, disculpa mi  lenta manera de razonar pero me estas diciendo que esos metodos van directamente en la clase agendaOdontologica si? enserio te agradezco ,e ayudas mucho

Comment: Yo lo veo como dos clases: AdministradorDeAgenda y Agenda. Administrador de agenda tiene los metodos crear y eliminar  ( agendas) . Y Agenda tiene los metodos obtenerDiasDisponibles, obtenerHorasDisponibles, registrarTurno, cambiarHoraDeTurno, etc.   Y administrador le ordena a AdministradorAgendas crear, eliminar, obtener una agenda.

Comment: muchas Gracias por tu tiempo y explicación